# How do I plot xtick values for my bar chart?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I don't understand how do I plot xticks on my graph. I want to use the 'Sport' column of my dataframe as my xticks value.

Data is in the image.

```
div1['Athletes'] = pd.to_numeric(div1.Athletes.str.replace(',', ''))
ax = div1[['Sport','Athletes']].plot(kind='bar', title="Number of Athletes in Men's Individual Sports in NCAA Division 1", figsize=(15, 10), legend=True, fontsize=12)
SportList = div1['Sport'].tolist()
ax.set_xticklabels(SportList)
```

Error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-4b8025d176c6> in <module>()
----> 1 div1['Athletes'] = pd.to_numeric(div1.Athletes.str.replace(',', ''))
  2 ax = div1[['Sport','Athletes']].plot(kind='bar', title="Number of Athletes in Men's Individual Sports in NCAA Division 1", figsize=(15, 10), legend=True, fontsize=12)
  3 SportList = div1['Sport'].tolist()
  4 ax.set_xticklabels(SportList)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in 
__getattr__(self, name)
   2738         if (name in self._internal_names_set or name in self._metadata or
   2739                 name in self._accessors):
-> 2740             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   2741         else:
   2742             if name in self._info_axis:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py in __get__(self, instance, owner)
    239             # this ensures that Series.str.<method> is well defined
    240             return self.accessor_cls
--> 241         return self.construct_accessor(instance)
    242 
    243     def __set__(self, instance, value): 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/strings.py in 
_make_str_accessor(self)
   1839             # (instead of test for object dtype), but that isn't practical for
   1840             # performance reasons until we have a str dtype (GH 9343)
-> 1841             raise AttributeError("Can only use .str accessor with string "
   1842                                  "values, which use np.object_ dtype in "
   1843                                  "pandas")

AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Athletes` series contains types which are *not* strings. If you are sure some of these values *are* strings, you can convert to `str` first before using the `.str` accessor:

```
div1['Athletes'] = pd.to_numeric(div1['Athletes'].astype(str).str.replace(',', ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

Before the `.plot` method, set the `DataFrame` index to 'Sport' and pandas will handle the rest:

```
ax = div1[['Sport','Athletes']].set_index('Sport').plot(kind='bar', title="Number of Athletes in Men's Individual Sports in NCAA Division 1", figsize=(15, 10), legend=True, fontsize=12, rot=0)
```

Comment: However, the xticks values are not oriented properly. How do I rotate them 90 degrees?

Comment: use  `rot` arguement. `.plot(kind='bar', rot=0)` for example

Comment: If I want to create another bar chart with the same X and Y axis but each bar should be next to the bar of the first dataset, how do I go about it? Do I need to change the width parameter?

Comment: If you mean you want the bars to be touching... like histogram style, then yes. Set `width=1`

Comment: If you mean adding a whole other Series to the plot, then include it like `div1[['Sport','Athletes', 'OtherData']]` ...

Comment: I want to add another Series to the plot, which is part of 2nd Dataframe ie I want to add div2['Athletes'].

Comment: I'd recommend merging the two DataFrames on a common field before plotting